# Injecting values into a dynamic component in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm working on a component that lets a user dynamically enter rules, these rules can be of different types and dependent on the rule type different values will be captured.

I've got the dynamic components being created my problem is passing in the initial values to the dynamically created component.

The values are completely different from rule to rule so I'm trying to use the useValue in the injector but its not able to resolve the parameters if I add a parameter to accept the values in the constructor.

My injector for the components:

```
getInjector(rule) {
  let inject = this.injectors[rule.name];
  if (!inject) {
    inject = Injector.create([{ provide: 'initialValues', useValue: rule.values }], this.inj);
    this.injectors[rule.name] = inject;
  }

  return inject;
}
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
export class MandatoryRuleComponent implements OnInit {
  values: any={};
  constructor(initialValues:any) { this.values = initialValues }

  ngOnInit() {
  if(!this.values.threshold){
    this.values.threshold = 9;
  }
 }
}
```

The complete code can be found on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-mjr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [get](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.9/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts#L70) passed value in your dynamic components. See [official example](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#example-1).

So, in your case do something like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-deprecated-rule',
  templateUrl: './deprecated-rule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deprecated-rule.component.css']
})
export class DeprecatedRuleComponent implements OnInit {

  values: any = {};

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get provided data
    this.values = this.injector.get('initialValues');

    if (!this.values.adjustment) {
      this.values.adjustment = 999;
    }
  }
}
```

also please note that

- *string* token is deprecated since v4 and you should use `Type<T>` or
  `InjectionToken<T>` instance instead
- `create(providers: StaticProvider[], parent?: Injector)` (function
  arguments) is deprecated since v5 and you should use the new
  signature `Injector.create(options)`:

  ```
  create(options: {providers: StaticProvider[], parent?: Injector, name?: string})
  ```

Updated [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-mjr-nmpdks?file=app%2FRules%2Foptional-rule%2Foptional-rule.component.ts)